# Citations when importing a .tex file into Lyx

Tags: lyx, citing, import

I relatively new to LaTeX and Lyx. I am using the Scrivener -> MMD -> LaTeX workflow.
For citations, I used Papers2, as it allows me to insert MMD-style citations into Scrivener.

When compiling, the MMD-citations turn into \citep (this sucks, but I will have to deal with it later).

Now when I import this .tex file into Lyx, the \citep commands are not translated into the Lyx citation thingy. Instead, they are placed into ERT-boxes. When trying to typeset this, I get a bunch of errors.

I put \bibliography(mathesis) in the preamble, it is in the same folder as the now imported file.

Am I forgetting something? It shouldn't matter whether the I am citing using the Lyx-specific process or ERT-boxes, right?

Edit: the errors I get now look like this

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Guicciardi:2009km' on page 7 undefined on input line 345.
```

This is how my preamble looks like:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliography{mathesis}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the errors (rather than just calling it "a bunch of errors"). However, you would need to include the [`natbib` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) as part of your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble for it to recognize `\citep`. Also, use `\bibliography{mathesis}`, not `\bibliography(mathesis)`.

Comment: This may be related to the fact that LyX does an automatic check to see whether it should perform a recompile or not, based on unresolved references. However, in terms of citation, you need to compile with BibTeX in order to extract the relevant information for it to be properly recognized by `natbib`.